# extract tags (words) from whole string

Tags: php, string

What's the optimal way to extract each words from a string such as:

```
one, two, "big three", four, "seven and eight"
```

where those surrounded with double quotes should be treated as a single element:

```
array("one", "two", "big three", "four", "seven and eight")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using php >= 5.3 then you have the function str_getcsv.

```
$tags = str_getcsv($tags, ',', '"', '\\');
$tags = array_map('trim', $tags);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a CSV parser, rather than rolling your own. PHP has a builtin function that does exactly what you want — [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php):

```
$tags = str_getcsv($string);
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    ...
}
```

Note that this requires PHP 5.3. The "User contributed notes" show many workarounds for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$tags = explode(',', $string);
foreach($tags as &$tag)
{
    $tag = trim($tag);
}
```

(code is not checked)

Comment: This will not treat certain input right such as: ... two, "big, three", four, ...

Comment: Why &$tag? This is discouraged since php5

Comment: @Ron: Really? Why? How are you supposed to iterate and modify now?

Comment: This is considered as bad programming style. Due to the fact, that this grammar lead to confusion. Alternative:
foreach($array as $key => $value) { $array[$key] = $value; }