# How to read a CSV string into an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split a comma delimited string into an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php)
>   [extract tags (words) from whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358871/extract-tags-words-from-whole-string)

I'm trying to read a long variable into an array.

Variable `$x = "text1", "text2", "text3",` etc...

```
$x = '"text1", "text2", "text3"';
```

Do I just call it into my array like:

```
array($x)?
```

This doesn't seem to work

I want the final product to be:

```
array("text1", "text2", "text3")
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT:

Ok, some specifics:

I'm trying to replace the date fields in the following array with many dynamically read dates:

```
$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2012-09-09", "2012-09-10"), 1, '');
```

I have the dynamically read dates in a variable $x. When I echo $x, I get something in the format "2012-09-09", "2012-09-10", "2012-09-09", "2012-09-10", "2012-09-09", "2012-09-10", etc

Thanks

Comment: That variable initiation is not valid PHP.

Comment: Why do you wanna do this way? I mean, giving commas is a non standard way right?

Comment: @SteveRobbins Not only in PHP. In all the langs this is not standard.

Comment: I am creating a variable from a very long process (that checks if files exist in directories. I'm trying to read those file names, surrounded by quotes, into an array.

Comment: $x= "text1 ,text2 ,text3"; ? what is correct variable initiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variable is a string like:

```
$x = '"text1", "text2", "text3"'
```

You can convert it to an array with [str_getcsv](http://php.net/str_getcsv) like the following:

```
$x = '"text1", "text2", "text3"';
$yourArray = str_getcsv($x);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input string is `'"text1", "text2", "text3"'`

You can use the following code to get an array with three string

```
print_r( 
   explode( ",", preg_replace('/[" ]*/', "", '"text1", "text2", "text3"'))
);
// Outputs Array ( [0] => text1 [1] => text2 [2] => text3 )
```

This assumes there are no spaces in your strings, you'll have to play with it if spaces are allowed

Comment: understood, but how do I get the "text1", "text2", etc out of the variable and into the array?

Comment: @Downvoters: This was posted before the answer was changed to make sense...

Comment: @JuanMendes If people do not remove their downvotes or just they don't let you know why, just delete the answer. As far our answers are correct...

Comment: @PraveenKumar I can't tell what you mean... but the answer has been updated to match the question as it stands

Comment: Even though we are right and in the good sense, helping someone, we are getting penalized for nothing!

Comment: @user1569034 My answer does work with your edit, for people who don't have PHP >=5.3

Comment: +1 Juan - I understand the annoyance of down-votes when they are not warranted.

Answer (score 0):

Explode it.  String becomes an array based on a delimiter.

```
$x = "text1,text2,text3";
$new_array = explode(',', $x);
```

This becomes:

```
Array
(
    [0] => text1
    [1] => text2
    [2] => text3
)
```