# php string with special character to array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a PHP variable called `$array`, which will output something like 
`"...", "...", "...", "...", ...` when `echo`'d
but `...` may content some character like `"` , `,` and spaces or may even contain `", "` 
How can I change it to an array like Array`([0] => ... [1] => ... [2] => ... [3] => ... etc)`?

Comment: Try [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) instead of echoing it

Comment: you can use the basic str_replace function

Comment: So basically you have a CSV?

Comment: may ... contain `", "` ?

Comment: ... may contain anything

Comment: I don't even understand if it's an array or an array-like string you want to convert into array... in that case, you need to `explode(', ', $array);` but if it can contain the match, you are suppose to show us a better example of real value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract tags (words) from whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358871/extract-tags-words-from-whole-string) also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761172/php-csv-string-to-array (except you're not opening a file)

Comment: See [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

Comment: But It doesn't work when ... contain `", "`

Comment: _What_ doesn't work? If you've tried something, include what you've tried in your question, along with the result and how the result differs from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

PHP [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$array = explode(",",$array);  // split the string into an array([0] => '"..."', etc)

foreach ($array as $entry) {
    // clean up the strings as needed
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the str_replace function :

```
   $str = "....'...,,,";

   $unwantedChars = array("'", ",");

   $cleanString = str_replace($unwantedChars, "",$str);

   echo $cleanString;
```

You can add as many characters in the unwantedChar array you want